# How can I make a map of lists in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of key-value pairs that I want to reduce. So given `[("a", 2), ("b", 3), ("a", 4)]`, I want to produce `Map ("a", [2, 4]), ("b", [3])`. I found `Data.Map.fromListWith`, and so I've been thinking it's something like `fromListWith (\x -> Data.List.insert x []) myList`, but I feel like there should already be something built-in for this sort of thing?

Comment: `fromListWith (++) [(k, [v]) | (k, v) <- myList]`, yeah.

Comment: the `f` in `fromListWith f` is triggered when the key is the same, so you don't need to `insert`: it is already working with the entry for that key.

Comment: (Or `fromAscList $ groupSort myList`. [`groupSort`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6.21/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:groupSort))